# Javascript || In sert object conditionally into array array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have following data,

```
const array1 = [{id:1,name:'john'},{id:2,name:'peter'}];
const userObject={};
```

and I am forming new array of object like ,

```
const newarray =[...array1, userObject];
```

My requirement is ,if userObject is empty {},then i dont want to pass it in new array like,

```
const newarray =[...array1];
```

else

```
const newarray =[...array1, userObject];
```

Comment: what's the problem here exactly? You just described what an if statement does.

Comment: if object is empty then dont push in new array,else push it

Comment: There is no question here. What is holding you back in doing what you describe?

Comment: @sourabhk just check whether `userObject` contains any keys, if yes then merge it otherwise don't